# T-SQL return all for a given month

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2000 (version 8); I would like to query and return all records for a given month.

I would provide the month and year and would get every record with a date falling within that period.

I'm hoping there is a way that is more elegant than what I've seen on google with looping through days or determining last day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest way but not performance efficient. as this query will not make use of any indexes defined on the DateColumn.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Name
WHERE MONTH(DateColumn) = 12    --<-- Month December
AND   YEAR(DateColumn)  = 2013  --<-- Year 2013
```

A better approach will be something like ...

For example if you want all the records in JUNE 2013 you could do something like .....

```
SELECT *
FROM DateColumn >= '20130601'
AND  DateColumn <= '20130630'
```

Comment: THANK YOU smart person.  I will accept answer in 8 min when timer expires :)

Answer (score 0):

From within Microsoft Query I use:
docdate

> =#1/09/2022# And <=#30/09/2022#

I'm still trying to find a more elegant way just to refer to all of the month before current.